# Automatically launching Firefox from terminal using at command

Tags: linux, terminal, scheduled-tasks, at-job

I am a beginner at linux and really enthusiastic to learn the OS. I am trying to launch Firefox(or any other software like Evince) from the command line as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# at 1637
[root@localhost ~]# at> firefox
[root@localhost ~]# at> ^d
```

The job gets scheduled without any error. But at the specified time it does not run. 
I also tried giving the following path:

```
[root@localhost ~]# at 1637
[root@localhost ~]# at> /usr/bin/firefox
[root@localhost ~]# at> ^d
```

Still no result. But When I try to use **echo** to display a text on the screen it appears at the specified time as desired. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not set DISPLAY. `at` will run in separate shell where display is not set.
try the following code.

```
dinesh:~$ at 2120
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at>  export DISPLAY=:0
at> /usr/bin/firefox > firefox.log 2>&1
at> <EOT>
job 7 at Tue Mar 11 21:20:00 2014
```

If it is still failing check `firefox.log` for more information.

Comment: I'll try with this. Where can I find more info on setting DISPLAY?

Comment: You can find bit more info [HERE](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/administrator/5.7.0_november_2010/html/tib_admin_install/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=tib_admin_install&file=install.3.16.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1) Its not always recommended to run things as root

2) You can also try `./firefox` if you are in the current  directory of firefox.  In linux you need to pay attention to your path variable.  Unless `.` (the current directory) is in your path you will have to type `./program` if the program is in the same directory as you.

Also you need to pay attention to file permissions:  In linux you have read-write-eXecute access.

`ls -l` will do a list of directories and show the file permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x   10 user  staff     340 Oct  6  2012 GlassFish_Server/
drwx------@  15 jeffstein  staff     510 Oct  6 15:01 Google Drive/
drwxr-xr-x   20 jeffstein  staff     680 May 14  2013 Kindle/
drwx------+  67 jeffstein  staff    2278 Jan 26 14:22 Library/
drwx------+  19 jeffstein  staff     646 Oct 23 18:28 Movies/
drwx------+  15 jeffstein  staff     510 Jan  3 20:29 Music/
drwx------+  90 jeffstein  staff    3060 Mar  9 20:23 Pictures/
drwxr-xr-x+   6 jeffstein  staff     204 Nov  3 21:16 Public/
drwxr-xr-x   22 jeffstein  staff     748 Jan 14  2012 androidTools/
-rwxrwxrwx    1 jeffstein  staff    1419 Aug 28  2013 color.sh*
```

This is an example of `ls -l` here you can see color.sh has -rwxrwxrwx that means that anybody can read or write or run the file.

Without actually knowing where you installed firefox however I can't be of more help but these are some small pointers which might help.

Comment: I have installed linux as a VM hence I am running it as root to avoid file permission issues. So you mean to say I cannot run any software unless I specify the path?

Comment: If firefox was installed in `/usr/bin/firefox` you could either change to /usr/bin and type ./firefox  or you could type /usr/bin/firefox and it should run.

Comment: This way I am able to launch it. If you could help me on how to schedule this to happen at a specified time using {at} command, it would be really helpful. I get a mail in my root account that says " cannot open display" .

Comment: have you looked at crontab?

Comment: Yes I did. It seems to be working with that. But I really wanted to grasp all the concepts properly so was trying hard to get the result with at

Answer (score 0):

try finding where firefox is actually installed using "whereis firefox" command.
Then try using that path in at command.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get directions on how to use a command type:

`man at`

this will display the "manual"

```
DESCRIPTION
     The at and batch utilities read commands from standard input or a speci-
     fied file.  The commands are executed at a later time, using sh(1).

     at      executes commands at a specified time;

     atq     lists the user's pending jobs, unless the user is the superuser;
             in that case, everybody's jobs are listed;

     atrm    deletes jobs;

     batch   executes commands when system load levels permit; in other words,
             when the load average drops below _LOADAVG_MX (1.5), or the value
             specified in the invocation of at run.
```

So obviously you need to schedule a job with `at` and you can see if it worked with `atq`

Read the manual and it should help - if i have more time I'll write you a quick example.

Comment: I'll use cron and get the result.